# User is always null when using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, openid, openid-connect, openid-provider

I'm trying to generate access tokens for my aspnet core web app. I created the following provider:

```
public class CustomOpenIdConnectServerProvider : OpenIdConnectServerProvider
    {
        public override Task ValidateTokenRequest(ValidateTokenRequestContext context)
        {
            // Reject the token requests that don't use grant_type=password or grant_type=refresh_token.
            if (!context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType() && !context.Request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
            {
                context.Reject(
                    error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                    description: "Only the resource owner password credentials and refresh token " +
                                 "grants are accepted by this authorization server");

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            // Since there's only one application and since it's a public client
            // (i.e a client that cannot keep its credentials private), call Skip()
            // to inform the server the request should be accepted without
            // enforcing client authentication.
            context.Skip();

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public override async Task HandleTokenRequest(HandleTokenRequestContext context)
        {
            // Resolve ASP.NET Core Identity's user manager from the DI container.
            var manager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();

            // Only handle grant_type=password requests and let ASOS
            // process grant_type=refresh_token requests automatically.
            if (context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
            {
                var user = await manager.FindByNameAsync(context.Request.Username);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.Reject(
                        error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        description: "Invalid credentials.");

                    return;
                }

                // Ensure the password is valid.
                if (!await manager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Request.Password))
                {
                    if (manager.SupportsUserLockout)
                    {
                        await manager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
                    }

                    context.Reject(
                        error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        description: "Invalid credentials.");

                    return;
                }

                if (manager.SupportsUserLockout)
                {
                    await manager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
                }

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationScheme);

                // Note: the name identifier is always included in both identity and
                // access tokens, even if an explicit destination is not specified.
                identity.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user));

                identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user));

                // When adding custom claims, you MUST specify one or more destinations.
                // Read "part 7" for more information about custom claims and scopes.
                identity.AddClaim("username", await manager.GetUserNameAsync(user),
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

                var claims = await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
                foreach (var claim in claims)
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(claim.Type, claim.Value, OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
                }

                // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                    new AuthenticationProperties(),
                    context.Options.AuthenticationScheme);


                // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
                ticket.SetScopes(
                    /* openid: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess,
                    /* email: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                    /* profile: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile);

                // Set the resource servers the access token should be issued for.
                ticket.SetResources("resource_server");

                context.Validate(ticket);
            }
        }
```

This works just fine, I can get the access token and the users are authenticated successfully. The issue that I'm facing here is that in any authorized action method when I do this: `var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` the value for `user` is always null! Of course, I'm passing the Authorization header with a valid access token and the request goes into actions annotated with `Authorize` without any problems. It's just the value of `user` is null. Can anybody tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)` uses the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` claim as the user identifier.

In your case, `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` - which is no longer considered by the OpenID Connect server middleware as a special claim in 1.0 - is not added to the access token because it doesn't have the appropriate destination. As a consequence, Identity is unable to extract the user identifier from the access token.

You have 3 options to fix that:

- Replace the default user identifier claim used by Identity by calling `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject);` in your `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method.
- Keep using the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` claim but give it the right destination (`OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken`).
- Use `UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.FindFirstValue(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject))` instead of `UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)`.